# Which physics quantities are real and which just a tool in the Newtonian apporach?

Tags: newtonian-mechanics

Assuming all frames are inertia, and considering an inelastic collision.

In which the answers suggested K.E. difference is frame dependent. 
but I have done calculation and found  K.E. difference is frame independent

Consider a frame of center of mass, and a frame A:

$
K_{center}=K_A-\frac{1}{2}\sum{m_i}\dot{R}^2...(1)
$

after a collision, the system lost a mount of energy in frame A, say 2/3 into heat.

$
K'_{center}=K'_A-\frac{1}{2}\sum{m_i}\dot{R}^2=\frac{1}{3}K_A-\frac{1}{2}\sum{m_i}\dot{R}^2...(2)
$

Hencer the energy difference in frame is:

$
K'_{center}-K_{center}=-\frac{2}{3}K_A ...(3)
$

Do the same thing on another frame B with ANY relative speed to frame A, and obtain:

$
K'_{center}-K_{center}=\Delta{K_B} ...(4)
$

Hence, given (3) and (4), we found K.E. difference is frame independent in an isolated system, as frame B is ANY inertia frame with any relative speed to A.

$
\Delta{K_B}=-\frac{2}{3}K_A
$

Check if it makes sense:

We don't get new particle by moving ourselves around a particle accelerator.

Nevertheless, what I am asking is something else:

Now switch our attention to a ruler.

If I tell you a number 5 with unit cm
it is quite pointless, if considering a question: what reality is it associated to?

but if I tell you a number 5 minus 0 with unit cm (or 7 minus 2)
then this is associated to "length".

Some boundaries seem to be at work.

I am thinking if:

Only the "difference" type physics quantities are useful in reality.

Since what is the point of K.E. which is frame dependent? How much does K.E.(frame dependent) tell us about reality?(Not much, you pick the frame and get different K.E.!)

However, difference in energy tell us a lot (in fact, conservation of energy is just complement of energy difference)

So at long last, my question is:
**Q: Is "absolute" physics quantities just a mathematical tool or something real? ("absolute" physics quantity is defined as: NOT difference type physics quantities)**

Furthermore: In quantum theory? In relativity theory?

Comment: what do you mean by physical meaning of something? Physical meaning of mass is that is is proportionality coefficient between force and acceleration, both of which are measurable. Physical meaning of (kinetic) energy is that if you heat gas up, molecules will move faster (also measurable quantity). It seems that you don't like that absolute value change when observer changes. So, that the way relativity principle works, nothing you can do about it.

Comment: I have to admit that I don't really understand what you are asking, but @aandreev compels me to respond with a philosophical argument.  Physics is a mathematical model of the real world--there is no "physical" meaning to physics beyond physics' ability to predict real world phenomena.  As soon as we see a theory mispredict something, we no longer consider it to be correct.

Comment: @aandreev I completely agree with Feynman, I prefer the quote: "People say to me are you looking for the ultimate laws of physics?  No I'm not, I'm just looking to find out more about the world.  And if it turns out there is a simple, ultimate law that explains everything--so be it...If it turns out it's like an onion with millions of layers and we're just sick and tired of looking at the layers, then that's the way it is!  But whatever way it comes out...nature is there and she's gonna come out the way she is!"

Comment: physical meaning means: Mathematics with physics reality/ Something real. Not just a tool. Beside, I feel kind of offended by your quotation. I don't think it is so philosophical. Since Purcell did discuss whether field is a tool or something real in his electricity and magnetism.

Comment: Also, you missed a point of K.E.; there is no such a thing as K.E. in Newton's mechanics. K.E. comes from work-energy theorm which give us only K.E. difference (energy transfer). I am okay with absolute value change when observer changes. but I do not like when I use sloppy thinking on something WITHOUT knowing its precise definition.

Comment: Second, "Physical meaning of (kinetic) energy is that if you heat gas up, molecules will move faster"
It is not the whole story. you don't measure different temperatures in different frame, you missed the role of entropy play in heat.

Comment: @ShingLau: The problem with "physical meaning means: mathematics with physics reality/something real" is that for every physical quantity in your theory of choice, you will find a theory of fundamental physics where is arises as some composite object, and then it will be easy to argue that it's just a tool. Quantum mechanics defines a force like F=ma as some average, and only late into the theory. Some recent theories will have space and time itself emerges form other quantities. What do you really mean with a question like "what does XXX tell us about reality?" and "physical sense"?

Comment: @NikolajK you have a point, I have to think of it.

Comment: @Jared thanks. it is how I think physics is as well. but I like to dig deeper and deeper in theories now and then.

Comment: For a closed system where momentum is conserved, the total KE change before and after is frame independent. For an individual particle it is not, that should fix your confusion.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The notion of "real quantities" and "tools" are theory dependant.
In a theory where space is supposed to be absolute, or where there is a privileged frame of reference, then the positions of space are seen as "real" and so is the privileged frame of reference.

A better formulated question would be to ask "what are the absolute quantities against the relative ones in a given theory?". This certainly makes much more sense.

In Newtonian mecanics, you have two kind of absolute quantities:

1) Galilean invariant quantities (the one who are the same in any inertial frames). Those, like mass, acceleration (and thus being inertial or not), difference of energy, and all the quantities you can build from the latter, are all absolutes in the above sense.

2) Quantities that are preserved during time-evolution seen from an inertial frame. Those are parametrizing motion, and are therefore also absolute if you transform them in the good manner. (Conservation of energy, kinetic energy when there is an elastic collision, linear momentum, angular momentum, ...).

Note, once again, that the notion of "realness" is theory dependant. It is precisely what a theory is made for actually: to tell you what is "real" from what is not.

Edit: Since Newton and Galileo, there is a quantity that is absolute in any of our theories: *change* or *acceleration*. Whole physics can be resumed as trying to make sense of *change*, the latter being formalized by acceleration in theory that respects (generalized) Galileo principle of inertia and invariance.

Comment: The way I learn thing is by constructing, rather than reading a direct solution, so I had to stop for one(maybe two) weeks before accepting your answer. And finally, I have some (convincing) thoughts on my question, and was planning to answer it my own, but after reading your answer again, I realized that you are right; furthermore, yet I can't explain this matter better than you did, so I choose your answer instead. 
Thank you for your elaborating answer.